# playing audio file at specific position in python

Tags: python, file, audio, playback

Is there a module that I could use for playing back an audio file in python? More specifically, I would like to have something where I can set the start and end positions of the playback. I need to play, say, for 5 seconds, then rewind the file by 5 second, and then play it again. After that I would want to move on to the next 5-second segment. I have looked at pygame and winsound, but it seems to me that they support only complete rewinds. Any comments on this? (I am developing for windows.)

Cheers,

v923z

Comment: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio/

Comment: Thanks Steve! I have complete forgotten about that that page. A very useful one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at using [pymedia](http://pymedia.org//index.html) specially its [player module](http://pymedia.org/docs/pymedia.player.html).

Comment: hi can u answer my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67062079/playing-part-of-audio-of-video-audio-file-from-a-specific-pointsecond-to-anoth ?

Answer (score 1):

PyMedia can not be installed using pip on Android. Using pygame instead meets the requirement. Here's a working snippet tested on both Windows 10 and Android. Note that the music file is a mp3 !

```
import pygame.mixer

#SOUND_FILE = 'c:/temp/JMJ.mp3'
SOUND_FILE = '/storage/emulated/0/music/JMJ.mp3'

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048) # if missing, the play speed will be too slow
pygame.mixer.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load(SOUND_FILE)
pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0, start=1626) # 1626 seconds from beginning

while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.event.wait()
```